# Liferay 7 LogFactoryUtil.getLogFactory().setLevel method

Tags: liferay-7

In liferay 6.2, I have been using the method:

```cs
LogFactoryUtil.getLogFactory().setLevel(String string , String string ,boolean boolean );
```

I try to use the same method in Liferay 7 but it is not included. I want to set the log level in my portlet but i can't find a method that can do that.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to bring this to you but as it turned out, the setLevel() method is removed from the LogFactory interface of Liferay. If you will look into the source code you will find that in Liferay 7, the LogFactory interface only has two overloaded versions of the method getLog(). You should post your question in Liferay community and they might provide you an alternative to this if there is any.